# Installing wkpdtothtml on Google Gloud Platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I created a node express application that acts as a print api based on the wkhtmltopdf plugin.

I am trying to deploy it to Google Cloud Platform, but I will need to install the wkhtmltopdf binaries on Google Cloud Platform first.

How do I go about this? I am using Google App Engine service.

Comment: I know this is a bad practice, but for quick workaround you can embed wkhtmltopdf s distribution to your code base and call its executable using relative path to it.

Comment: @serifcetiner I am actually trying to do that with the code below:

    // import wkhtmltopdf 
    var wkhtmltopdf = require('wkhtmltopdf');
    wkhtmltopdf.command = "/home/mikeaxle2006/wkhtlmtox/bin/wkhtmltopdf";

but i still get this 'error: Error: /bin/bash: wkhtmltopdf: command not found.'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: since it is not installed to your system, this package says "First, you need to install the wkhtmltopdf command line tool on your system." you need to download it from https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html 
then; open this in a path you like. 

in package code base there is:

wkhtmltopdf.command = 'wkhtmltopdf';
wkhtmltopdf.shell = '/bin/bash';

build your path using both

Answer (score 0):

You will need to build a custom runtime. From [About Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/about-custom-runtimes):

> Custom runtimes allow you to define new runtime environments, which
>   might include additional components like language interpreters or
>   application servers.

And from [Building Custom Runtimes](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/custom-runtimes/build) (you should probably go through that entire doc):

> To create a custom runtime you need:
>
> - An `app.yaml` file that describes your application's runtime configuration.
> - A `Dockerfile` that configures the runtime environment. In many cases, this can be just one line specifying a base image.
> - To ensure your application is listening on port 8080 and has request handlers that respond to lifecycle events, such as start, stop, and
>     health check requests.

Answer (score 0):

Create an app.yaml file with custom runtime, like below:

```
runtime: custom
env: flex
```

Create a Dockerfile to install some third party services. Example nginx image as below:

```
# Debian-based Linux operating system based on free software.
FROM ubuntu

# Install wkhtmltopdf
WORKDIR ~
RUN wget https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/releases/download/0.12.3/wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz
RUN tar vxf wkhtmltox-0.12.3_linux-generic-amd64.tar.xz 
RUN cp wkhtmltox/bin/wk* /usr/local/bin/
```